# Flat color each triangle in a mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

Im trying to make a 'n' sided mesh with a custom color for each triangle, I can select how many sides it has, the radius, and i'm struggling with the color. I want to put a random color on each drawn triangle, now that works, but I don't want it to blend with the other colors, I want it to be a flat color.

Shoud I make a material for each triangle via code and assign it to a triangle?, maybe a shader?. I dont know too much about materials or shaders, but willing to learn, just need to know what would be the best solution and maybe how to apply it.[this is an Example of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdAyz.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class CreateSectionMesh : MonoBehaviour {
    //Sides of the Plane
    [Range(3, 100, order = 1)]
    [SerializeField]
    int NumberOfSides = 3;
    //Radius of the plane
    [Range(10, 100, order = 1)]
    [SerializeField]
    int ShapeRadius = 10;

    // Just setup everything from the start to test...
    void Start() {

        Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[NumberOfSides + 1];
        //With this I can know the angle for each triangle
        float angle = 2 * Mathf.PI / NumberOfSides;
        vertices[0] = new Vector3(0, 0);
        Color[] colors = new Color[vertices.Length];

        //Set the vertices
        for (int i = 1; i <= NumberOfSides; i++) {
            vertices[i] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(i * angle), Mathf.Cos(i * angle)) * ShapeRadius;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= NumberOfSides; i++) {
            Debug.LogFormat("Vertices: {0}", vertices[i]);
        }
        
        //Setup the triangles to draw them properly
        int[] triangles = new int[3 * NumberOfSides];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfSides; i++) {
            triangles[3 * i] = 0;
            triangles[3 * i + 1] = i + 1;
            triangles[3 * i + 2] = i + 2 > NumberOfSides ? i + 2 - NumberOfSides : i + 2;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i++) {
            Debug.Log(triangles[i]);
        }

        //Finally the color for each triangle, but is blending with each near driangle color...
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++) {
            colors[i] = new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f));
        }

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.colors = colors;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        mesh.Optimize();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you're making your own mesh you could probably just assign UV values to each vertex that correspond with different colors in a texture.